# How can I contribute to base R in small ways?

Tags: r

Occasionally I see small ways I could improve either R (recently the IQR command) and R documentation (just this week perhaps elaborating differences among and better interconnecting aggregate, tapply, and by).  But I don't see a way to really make that contribution back.  I looked into the developer site and it seems that my options are either to attempt to become a full fledged developer or create packages, neither of which fit what I wish to accomplish.

I did propose IQR changes on the R mailing list but got no response so I figure that's going nowhere.

And to clarify, I'm talking about base-R.  Additional packages are another matter.

Any tips?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Send (or CC) to r-devel. Traffic is quite high on r-help, and things can be overlooked there.

[File a bug](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html) under the wishlist category detailing the improvement you would like to see.

Having filed the bug, try to provide a patch against the R code and or documentation as appropriate. I've done this before where there was a problem or infelicity in R, supplied a patch and a fix to the help files/manual and had the changes accepted (after suitable modification) by R Core.

If it is an addition to the R code base, you are going to have to show that there is a real pressing need for the addition. Basically you are asking R Core to maintain your code in perpetuity, and they are unlikely to do that unless you can demonstrate a need.

If it is an addition, look for a popular R package that does similar/related things and suggest to the package maintainer that they include your function. That way you don't need to start a whole package for something simple but contribute your code. There are several, popular, `*misc` packages on CRAN for example.

If you want to contribute fixes to the R documentation and/or manuals, provide patches to the sources. You can find the sources at [svn.r-project.org/R](http://svn.r-project.org/R)

Hopefully that gives you some ideas. Patches and code always help!

Comment: As an update, I posted to r-devel and the changes to IQR I was looking for are incorporated into the current version of R---starting at 2.13 I believe.

Comment: If I've found a typo in the docs, is there a quick and easy way to fix it? I can't get my head around the file layout of svn.r-project.org/R.

Comment: @smacdonald easy for whom? You could just email R-devel indicating exactly where in the **sources** (line number, file, etc) for the development version, i.e. trunk in the svn repo. Better to work out where the typo is in the svn, download that file and edit it, and then do a diff patch between your edited version and the downloaded one. Find out which package the function lives that has the typo in it, you should find the Rd files in the man folder in the library folder in the sources, e.g. [here]( http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/)

Comment: GavinSimpson, please don't [revert the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4054655/revisions), this is a great answer but hard to read and doesn't show hierarchy. (For example, are we supposed to assume the dangling *"File a bug under the wishlist category"* still applies as far down as *"If you want to contribute to R documentation..."* or not? It's very unclear. And every community has its own practices about (say) docbugs)

Comment: @smci I disagree, and I especially disagreed with the indentation of bullets implying they were subsidiary to a particular point. That's not how I intended the response to be read. For personal reasons I didn't have time today to change your edit or come up with different forms of words so it didn't need to be all in bullets.

Comment: What are patches ? Too much jargon in this post

Comment: @julien LMFGTFY or not, I’m that lazy. In this context, where we’re discussing contributing to a software project, it’s not unreasonable to expect people to know what a patch is.

Answer (score 6):

How about patches to existing packages?

How about open bug reports on packages?  [R-Forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org) projects don't seem to use the issue trackers much, but some folks on the [RPostgreSQL](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/) team I'm on enabled it (where it is hosted on Google Code), and it has been helpful -- [see here](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/issues/list).  And we had a really useful inflow of fresh blood with a rocking new developer from Japan, probably in part because of the visibility of the project there.

In essence, try to find a project / group / team to become acquainted with and join.  In that sense, this is just like any other Open Source project.  The r-devel list ([gmane view](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel)) is a good place for R development in general.

The R Core team, on the other hand, is a little more closed and per invitation only and unlikely to change.  So be it, for better or worse.  It has worked so far, and hence I am not among those who bemoan this loudly.

Comment: What if you aren't trying to 'join the team' but instead just do the R equivalent of a python PEP? That is just propose small simple changes are only for the better?

Are you saying that too is unrealistic?