# Differences between p-values in summary and from the anova in R lm()

Tags: r, lm

I am seeing differences in the p-value for the anova depending on how I access this.

Is there a way to get the same value that is returned by the summary?

One easy to represent case returns < 2.2e-16 in the summary and in the anova but gives me 8.129959e-100 when I access the value directly:

```
x <- lm(formula = eruptions ~ waiting, data = faithful)
summary(x)
anova(x)
anova(x)$"Pr(>F)"[1]
```

In another more difficult to represent case (there is a lot more data) I get p-value: < 2.2e-16 in the summary but 0 from anova.

Is there any way to get the actual value that is returned in the summary and anova?

I really appreciate your help -

Comment: Well, I don't see any difference here, except that one result is exact and the other one is more of an approximation ? 8.129959e-100 < 2.2e-16 is true, and 0 < 2.2e-16 is true, too.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't asking if they were different. I was asking how to get the value that shows up in the summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to dig into `stats:::print.summary.lm`.  The value isn't stored in the `summary.lm` object, it's computed on the fly from the `fstatistic` component of the object.

```
s <- summary(x)$fstatistic
(p <- pf(s["value"], s["numdf"], s["dendf"], lower.tail = FALSE))
##         value 
## 8.129959e-100
```

... and it's identical to the value produced by `anova()` ...

... and as @Dason points out below you can use `format.pval()` to get back to the display format of `summary()`:

```
format.pval(p)
## [1] "< 2.22e-16"
```

I can't see any way, short of hacking `print.summary.lm` for yourself, to override the `format.pval()` call within it to print out the full p-value in the summary.

Comment: stats:::print.summary.lm is what I was looking for. Thanks so much for taking the time to post.

Comment: Also note that if you want the value printed you can use `format.pval` to get the "< 2.2e-16"

Comment: Awesome!! Curious is why p-value is not stored in summary like other outputs. It would be just easy getting from: summary(x)[[12]].

Comment: Consistency is not one of R's greatest virtues :-) The `summary` functions for various classes were written at different times by different people ... (In other words, there's no good reason that I know of for the inconsistency.)  You could post a wishlist request to http://bugs.r-project.org , or raise the possibility on `r-devel@r-project.org` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054585/how-can-i-contribute-to-base-r-in-small-ways )